# Change monthcolor of calendarview (Android)

Tags: android, android-calendar

Anyone that can tell me how to change the color of the month in the `calendarview`, can't find any reasonable attributs in styles.xml (android theme) to change from--

Code:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
<item name="android:calendarViewStyle">@style/Calendar</item>
</style>

<style name="Calendar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.CalendarView">
<item name="android:weekNumberColor">#66FFFFFF</item>
<item name="android:weekDayTextAppearance">@style/weekDays</item>
</style>

<style name="weekDays">
<item name="android:textColor">#66FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set the text color of calendar view month name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411685/set-the-text-color-of-calendar-view-month-name)

Answer (score 2):

```
 android:theme="@style/testTheme"
```

Use this theme or a custom theme which has parent as this theme.

To make it white

To Choose other than white change the color use the following

```
android:textColorPrimary="@color/yourColor"
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any attribute for this setting. Kindly see the answer by Ryan, he drove a way out. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13621017/1723819