# Set the text color of calendar view month name

Tags: java, android

In android , i am using an default CalendarView.
I have set the background to light gray color. But can i change the color of month view of calendar view?

Comment: I have gone through the source code of the CalendarView , and i found out that there an texview mMonthTextView.. but it is not accessible outside.. so there's no way to set the text color of that textview..

Comment: wjat about styles? might be able to set it in the manifest

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you've found out, the TextView is private, and there does not seem to be any methods for accessing it.

Although I wouldn't recommend it, you can accomplish this using the `java.lang.reflect` package:

```
    try
    {
        CalendarView cv = (CalendarView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
        Class<?> cvClass = cv.getClass();
        Field field = cvClass.getDeclaredField("mMonthName");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        try
        {
            TextView tv = (TextView) field.get(cv);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        } 
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: @Ryan I want to change the name of the month that appears at the top and I can do it using this way. However, the date changes back to normal whenever I scroll the calendarview up or down. any hints ?

Comment: @tony9099 No simple way of doing that comes to mind, unfortunately. You can see the code for CalendarView [here at grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/widget/CalendarView.java). `setMonthDisplayed` is the method called to update the TextView.

Comment: @Tim see my answer for working solution for Android 5.x

Answer (score 6):

On Android 5.x I have used the following solution (it works on older versions too):

```
CalendarView cv = (CalendarView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendarView1);
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) cv.getChildAt(0);
View child = vg.getChildAt(0);

if(child instanceof TextView) {
    ((TextView)child).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
}
```

The layout for calendarview can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.0_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/calendar_view.xml?av=f), and based on that the month name TextView is the first child in the layout.