# setEmptyView when edittext is empty using textwatcher

Tags: android, android-calendar

I'm using a custom calendar from this [link](https://www.toptal.com/android/android-customization-how-to-build-a-ui-component-that-does-what-you-want). Its working but the dates of all the months except current month has been grayed out. I want to display all months when viewed like the 2nd screenshot. But it grays out all months except the current month (i.e. April). Can anyone help me in displaying each month like the 2nd screenshot and not like 1st screenshot?

```html
Calendar View:

public class CalendarView extends LinearLayout
{
 // for logging
 private static final String LOGTAG = "Calendar View";

 // how many days to show, defaults to six weeks, 42 days
 private static final int DAYS_COUNT = 42;

 // default date format
 private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "MMM yyyy";

 // date format
 private String dateFormat;

 // current displayed month
 private Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

 //event handling
 private EventHandler eventHandler = null;

 // internal components
 private LinearLayout header;
 private ImageView btnPrev;
 private ImageView btnNext;
 private TextView txtDate;
 private GridView grid;

 // seasons' rainbow
 int[] rainbow = new int[] {
   R.color.summer,
   R.color.fall,
   R.color.winter,
   R.color.spring
 };

 // month-season association (northern hemisphere, sorry australia :)
 int[] monthSeason = new int[] {2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2};

 public CalendarView(Context context)
 {
  super(context);
 }

 public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
 {
  super(context, attrs);
  initControl(context, attrs);
 }

 public CalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
 {
  super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  initControl(context, attrs);
 }

 /**
  * Load control xml layout
  */
 private void initControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
 {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  inflater.inflate(R.layout.control_calendar, this);

  loadDateFormat(attrs);
  assignUiElements();
  assignClickHandlers();

  updateCalendar();
 }

 private void loadDateFormat(AttributeSet attrs)
 {
  TypedArray ta = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CalendarView);

  try
  {
   // try to load provided date format, and fallback to default otherwise
   dateFormat = ta.getString(R.styleable.CalendarView_dateFormat);
   if (dateFormat == null)
    dateFormat = DATE_FORMAT;
  }
  finally
  {
   ta.recycle();
  }
 }
 private void assignUiElements()
 {
  // layout is inflated, assign local variables to components
  header = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.calendar_header);
  btnPrev = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.calendar_prev_button);
  btnNext = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.calendar_next_button);
  txtDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.calendar_date_display);
  grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.calendar_grid);
 }

 private void assignClickHandlers()
 {
  // add one month and refresh UI
  btnNext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
    currentDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    updateCalendar();
   }
  });

  // subtract one month and refresh UI
  btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
  {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
    currentDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);
    updateCalendar();
   }
  });

  // long-pressing a day
  grid.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
  {

   @Override
   public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> view, View cell, int position, long id)
   {
    // handle long-press
    if (eventHandler == null)
     return false;

    eventHandler.onDayLongPress((Date)view.getItemAtPosition(position));
    return true;
   }
  });
 }

 /**
  * Display dates correctly in grid
  */
 public void updateCalendar()
 {
  updateCalendar(null);
 }

 /**
  * Display dates correctly in grid
  */
 public void updateCalendar(HashSet<Date> events)
 {
  ArrayList<Date> cells = new ArrayList<>();
  Calendar calendar = (Calendar)currentDate.clone();

  // determine the cell for current month's beginning
  calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
  int monthBeginningCell = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;

  // move calendar backwards to the beginning of the week
  calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -monthBeginningCell);

  // fill cells
  while (cells.size() < DAYS_COUNT)
  {
   cells.add(calendar.getTime());
   calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
  }

  // update grid
  grid.setAdapter(new CalendarAdapter(getContext(), cells, events));

  // update title
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
  txtDate.setText(sdf.format(currentDate.getTime()));

  // set header color according to current season
  int month = currentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  int season = monthSeason[month];
  int color = rainbow[season];

  header.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(color));
 }


 private class CalendarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Date>
 {
  // days with events
  private HashSet<Date> eventDays;

  // for view inflation
  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  public CalendarAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Date> days, HashSet<Date> eventDays)
  {
   super(context, R.layout.control_calendar_day, days);
   this.eventDays = eventDays;
   inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
  {
   // day in question
   Date date = getItem(position);
   int day = date.getDate();
   int month = date.getMonth();
   int year = date.getYear();

   // today
   Date today = new Date();

   // inflate item if it does not exist yet
   if (view == null)
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.control_calendar_day, parent, false);

   // if this day has an event, specify event image
   view.setBackgroundResource(0);
   if (eventDays != null)
   {
    for (Date eventDate : eventDays)
    {
     if (eventDate.getDate() == day &&
       eventDate.getMonth() == month &&
       eventDate.getYear() == year)
     {
      // mark this day for event
      view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.reminder);
      break;
     }
    }
   }

   // clear styling
   ((TextView)view).setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
   ((TextView)view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

   if (month != today.getMonth() || year != today.getYear())
   {
    // if this day is outside current month, grey it out
    ((TextView)view).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.greyed_out));
   }
   else if (day == today.getDate())
   {
    // if it is today, set it to blue/bold
    ((TextView)view).setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    ((TextView)view).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.today));
   }

   // set text
   ((TextView)view).setText(String.valueOf(date.getDate()));

   return view;
  }
 }

 /**
  * Assign event handler to be passed needed events
  */
 public void setEventHandler(EventHandler eventHandler)
 {
  this.eventHandler = eventHandler;
 }

 /**
  * This interface defines what events to be reported to
  * the outside world
  */
 public interface EventHandler
 {
  void onDayLongPress(Date date);
 }
}
```

[image: 2nd Screenshot[![][2]]
[image: 1st Screenshot]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411685/set-the-text-color-of-calendar-view-month-name

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Please check the code inside getView() in the condition `if(month != today.getMonth() || year != today.getYear())`. That's what graying out the dates.

Answer (score 0):

Get the date that is set in the heade, **using txtDate.getText();**

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    Date currentSelectedDate = sdf.parse(using txtDate.getText());


if (month != currentSelectedDate.getMonth() || year != currentSelectedDate.getYear())
```