# Android Calendar View change text color

Tags: java, android, calendarview

I have a `CalendarView` in my app. But I would like to have the background of the `CalendarView` black and the text inside the `CalendarView` white. But in xml there is no `TextColor=` in the `CalendarView`. So how can I change the text of the `CalendarView`?

I have tried every solution on StackOverflow and the internet so far. I've managed to change the color of the days in the CalendarView but not the month and year.

I've tried both methods in this post: [Set the text color of calendar view month name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411685/set-the-text-color-of-calendar-view-month-name)

And I've tried this method:
[Change CalendarView style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style?rq=1)

And some other I found on the internet but nothing was succesfull.

Comment: Please look at this previous [questioin.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style)

Answer (score 8):

> Set style in your **CalendarView**

```
<CalendarView
    android:id="@+id/calendarView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:theme="@style/CalenderViewCustom"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewDateCustomText"
    android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText" />
```

> Inside Style.xml

```
    <style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/red</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CalenderViewDateCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:weekNumberColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CalenderViewWeekCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Color of calendar view month name is white here.

Answer (score 4):

```
android:theme="@style/testTheme"
```

Use this theme or a custom theme which has parent as this theme.

To make it white

To Choose other than white change the color use the following

```
android:textColorPrimary="@color/yourColor"
```

or other text colors use the following

```
android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/weekDayTextAppearance"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@style/appTextAppearance"
    android:unfocusedMonthDateColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
    android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
    android:weekSeparatorLineColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
    android:focusedMonthDateColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
    android:weekNumberColor="@color/colorLoginBtn"
```