# How to change Month text color in CalendarView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-styles, calendarview

I use CalendarView in my project and I need to make a special design for it. I can change colours of all things in CalendarView but only not colour of month on the top of calendar. I tried all attributes in xml. How I can change colour of month incription and arrows?

```
<CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Heh"
        android:maxDate="31/12/2018"
        android:minDate="09/01/2012"
        android:showWeekNumber="false"
        android:focusedMonthDateColor="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:background="#004366"
        android:unfocusedMonthDateColor="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:dateTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:weekDayTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:weekSeparatorLineColor="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:selectedWeekBackgroundColor="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        />
```

[image]

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LinearLayout ll= (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_moi, null, false);

    CalendarView cv = (CalendarView) ll.getChildAt(0);
    Long maxData = System.currentTimeMillis();
    cv.setMaxDate(maxData);

    cv.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                        int dayOfMonth) {


        }
    });

    new AlertDialog.Builder(ItemClassActivity.this)
            .setTitle("")
            .setMessage("")
            .setView(ll)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            }
    ).show();
```

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411685/set-the-text-color-of-calendar-view-month-name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change CalendarView style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412402/change-calendarview-style)

Comment: @Dhashri, I added part of code into question after picture. I use this CalendarView in AlertDialog, so it does not work for me

Comment: @user392117, in this answer there are all about changing style, but not about month

Answer (score 8):

Having defined following in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="CustomCalendarMonth" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomCalendarDay" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/green</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomCalendarWeek" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/purple</item>
</style>
```

Then in xml:

```
<CalendarView
    android:theme="@style/CustomCalendarMonth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CustomCalendarDay"
    android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CustomCalendarWeek" />
```

Here will be the output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Check this code@Valentin.May be it will help you.You can change months by clicking on side buttons.

I used this library :

```
implementation 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:1.9.1'
```

**Calendar.xml**

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout_detail"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

    android:id="@+id/toolbar"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"

    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/image_back"

        android:layout_width="30dp"

        android:layout_height="20dp"

        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"

        android:text="Calendar"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        android:textSize="17dp"

        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/text_today"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_gravity="center|right"

        android:padding="10dp"

        android:text="Today"

        android:textColor="@android:color/white"

        android:textSize="15dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="400dp"

    android:layout_margin="10dp"


    android:gravity="center"

    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="60dp"

        android:gravity="center"

        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/layout_right"

            android:layout_width="40dp"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="20dp"

                android:layout_height="20dp"

                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/text"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:text="Date"

                android:textColor="@color/red_shade_dashboard"

                android:textSize="17dp"

                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/layout_left"

            android:layout_width="40dp"

            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageView

                android:layout_width="20dp"

                android:layout_height="20dp"

                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="1dp"

        android:background="@color/red_shade_dashboard" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_weight="0.2">

        <com.github.sundeepk.compactcalendarview.CompactCalendarView

            android:id="@+id/compactcalendar_view"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="320dp"

            android:layout_margin="5dp"

            app:compactCalendarBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"

            app:compactCalendarCurrentDayBackgroundColor="@color/red_shade_dashboard"
            app:compactCalendarCurrentSelectedDayBackgroundColor="@color/red_shade_dashboard"
            app:compactCalendarMultiEventIndicatorColor="@color/red_shade_dashboard"
            app:compactCalendarTargetHeight="360dp"

            app:compactCalendarTextColor="@android:color/black"

            app:compactCalendarTextSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**CalendarActivity.java**

```
public class CalenderViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

CompactCalendarView compactCalendarView;
private SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
private SimpleDateFormat DateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
TextView tx_date, tx_today;
LinearLayout ly_detail;
LinearLayout ly_left, ly_right;
Calendar myCalendar;
ImageView im_back;
Date c;
SimpleDateFormat df;
String formattedDate;
String[] dates = new String[0];
RecyclerView recyclerView;
TextView tx_item;

String[] day={"10","20","21","25","27"};
String[] month={"10","10","11","11","12"};
String[] year ={"2018","2018","2018","2018","2018"};

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calender_view);

    init();
    calendarlistener();
    Setdate();


    tx_date.setText(""+formattedDate);


    ly_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            compactCalendarView.showCalendarWithAnimation();
            compactCalendarView.showNextMonth();
        }
    });

    ly_left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            compactCalendarView.showCalendarWithAnimation();
            compactCalendarView.showPreviousMonth();
        }
    });

    tx_today.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(CalenderViewActivity.this, CalenderViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

        }
    });

    im_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });


}

//variable initialization

public void init() {
    compactCalendarView = (CompactCalendarView) findViewById(R.id.compactcalendar_view);
    tx_date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    ly_left = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_left);
    ly_right = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_right);
    im_back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_back);
    tx_today = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_today);
    ly_detail = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_detail);



}


//calendar method

public void calendarlistener() {
    compactCalendarView.setListener(new CompactCalendarView.CompactCalendarViewListener() {
        @Override

        public void onDayClick(Date dateClicked) {

            if ( DateFormat.format(dateClicked).equals("2018-11-21")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),DateFormat.format(dateClicked)+" This day your brother birth day ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),DateFormat.format(dateClicked)+" In This day no Events Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

        @Override

        public void onMonthScroll(Date firstDayOfNewMonth) {

            compactCalendarView.removeAllEvents();
            Setdate();
            tx_date.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(firstDayOfNewMonth));

        }
    });
}

//get current date

public void Setdate() {


    c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    formattedDate = df.format(c);

    compactCalendarView.setUseThreeLetterAbbreviation(true);

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");


    myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    for (int j = 0; j < month.length; j++) {

        int mon = Integer.parseInt(month[j]);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.parseInt(year[j]));
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mon - 1);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.parseInt(day[j]));

        Event event = new Event(Color.RED, myCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), "test");
        compactCalendarView.addEvent(event);
    }
}
```

**output** - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYUdl.png